# Devstack: "Authentication Required" error

Tags: openstack

I installed Openstack using Devstack on my ubuntu VM. On my local.conf file i only specified the cloud ip.

(HOST_IP=ip of the vm. )

Now when i try to connect to one of my services using browser(Compute, Orchestration, Volume ecc, Compute for exaple has the following url: http://192.168.0.9:8004/v1/2ba712fbd1244b2e85878850e51a6f63 ) i met an error message as output:

Authentication Required

I need to connect to those service since I want to connect the cloud to Scalr. I think it's a problem about ketstone token or something similar, can someone give me an dvise? Thx ^^

/--------------/

That's the output of "heat -d stack-list"  after i source the RC file: 
link: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2a00oqr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect directly to the openstack heat service, without going through keystone authentication first.

In openstack, you log in to the openstack keystone service, receive an authentication token and pass that token to the service you want to use. If you get an "Authentication Required" error, it probably means that you did not pass the authentication token.

Try using the openstack CLI with the 'debug' option - this will show you the API calls that are being sent. (http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/heatclient_commands.html)

If you have the rc file for your account, you first need to 'source' the file, and then execute the CLI commands:

```
source <tenant>.rc
heat stack-list
```

Comment: Since i'm using Devstack i thought that the Keystone authentication was included on istallation.

Comment: I downloaded my RC File and i run it, then i used the command line "keystone token-get" but i still met same error. I have to restart the cloud?

Comment: I updated my answer - the rc file should not be 'run' - because then then changes will not be applied to the current shell. You need to use the 'source' command.

Comment: Sooooo , following your answer i 1) source rcfile-sh  then 2) source <tenant name>.rc 3) heat stack-list? Ok i will try.

Comment: 1) source rcfile.sh, 2) heat stack-list

Comment: Uhm i did as you say but i still can't connect to URL Service (ex  http://192.168.0.9:8004/v1 ). Did i need to restart some service?

Comment: No. Run the command with the debug flag and add the output to your question

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should create openstack rc file (adminrc.sh for example)
   [OpenStack RC file](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/user-guide/common/cli-set-environment-variables-using-openstack-rc.html)
2. And after you enter server you should load this file first ". adminrc.sh"

**UPDATE**

You can just use openrc file in devstack folder:

```
. openrc admin admin
```

or you can create new source file (nano rcfile.sh):

```
export OS_USERNAME=username admin
export OS_PASSWORD=password
export OS_TENANT_NAME=projectName
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://identityHost:portNumber/v2.0 #url was showed in the end of stack.sh output (example http://192.168.2.100/identity)
# The following lines can be omitted
export OS_TENANT_ID=tenantIDString
export OS_REGION_NAME=regionName
export OS_CACERT=/path/to/cacertFile
```

And use it like this:

```
. rcfile.sh
```

Comment: please provide the required information from the resource. and reference the original

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/518306)